# Show final two digits in attribute using dynamic text in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, dynamic-text, plss

I am making a map of a project. for the dynamic labels it has the township and range values as separate attributes in the table, but the only spot where it identifies the section number is here. The last two digits. So it is Township (39) Range (04) Section (10). Is there a way with dynamic labels to just have the last two digits of the PLSS name attribute to show?

[image]

Comment: In ArcGIS Pro, Arcade is the default labeling language/engine:  `Right($feature.PLSSName, 2)`

Comment: If it's an integer field, modulus 100, then change to string.

Comment: Ooops, I completely missed that ArcGIS was the software, had my QGIS blinkers on. I've deleted my answer that refers to QGIS, sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can label with the Arcade expression
`right($feature.name, 2)`:

[right function](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/function-reference/text_functions/#right)

[image]